# How to make previous and next button for tabs using bootstrap ,jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

Below I have added dynamic tabs with content working code now I want to add previous and next button in this.

If I press next it should move to menu1, menu2, menu3 with tabs content
and if I press previous it should move to previous tabs with responding data .how can I make this using jquery?
anyone help me out to move forward

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".nav-tabs a").click(function(){
        $(this).tab('show');
    });
});
```

```html
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <h2>Dynamic Tabs</h2>
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="active"><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#menu1">Menu 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#menu2">Menu 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#menu3">Menu 3</a></li>
  </ul>

  <div class="tab-content">
    <div id="home" class="tab-pane fade in active">
      <h3>HOME</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="menu1" class="tab-pane fade">
      <h3>Menu 1</h3>
      <p>Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="menu2" class="tab-pane fade">
      <h3>Menu 2</h3>
      <p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="menu3" class="tab-pane fade">
      <h3>Menu 3</h3>
      <p>Eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo.</p>
    </div>     
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an approximation of how you would solve this problem.

1. You can get the selected tab using a query selector like this `.nav-tabs>li.active`
2. Once you have the active tab, you can use the `nextElementSibling` or `previousElementSibling` property to get the next or previous tab , see [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NonDocumentTypeChildNode/nextElementSibling) for details.
3. Once you have the next tab, you can call show on it.

Comment: i tired ny best but i am not able to solve can you please help me out